# MapReduce Inner Join?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to join log entry with GeoIP database. Here is what I have.

1. In my log file I am extracting IP address (foreign key) as a Key. And rest entry as a value.
2. In GeoIP database I have range of IP map to a particular Country (IPFROM, IPTO, Country).

Now I am not sure How to go about joining these two fields and which join to use.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly , you want to get the country name for a given Ip address inlog file.

You can create some csv by exporting your database table.

and then you can use distributed cache concept to read that file

Comment: Agree with that. But then how to map Country with IP as GeoIP has a range of IP maps to a country?

Comment: Please post one sample record of database and one sample line from log file

Comment: are the ip ranges of fixed length?

Comment: Ip Record:                                             `208.76.134.132 - - [23/Oct/2012:03:18:09 +0000] "PUT /apple/apple.htm
HTTP/1.1" 200 1809 "-" "MDM/1.0"`                                                                                                                                                                    GeoIP Data: `"2.58.64.0","2.58.143.255","UA","Kyiv city","Kiev"`